# Function to parse VB.NET Like pattern

Tags: c#, parsing, lexical-analysis

VB.NET has a [`Like` operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) with a paradigm similar to the standard SQL `LIKE` expression ([SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)), but with a different syntax:

```
Dim result As Boolean = "abcd" Like "a*"
```

It supports:

- multiple-character matches -- `"abcd" Like "a*"`
- single-character matches -- `"abcd" Like "a??d"`
- digit matches -- `"ab12cd" Like "ab##cd"`
- alternate character matches -- `"abcd" Like "[aeiou]bcd"`
- ranges within the alternate character matches -- `"abcd" Like "[a-n]bcd"`
- negation of alternate characters -- `"abcd" Like "[!e-z]bcd"`

I've written code that tokenizes these patterns into a data structure, using the [OneOf library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) which provides discriminated unions for C#. (The ultimate purpose is to convert the VB Like syntax to SQL LIKE syntax.)

I'm looking for feedback in the following areas:

- correctness, even in edge cases
- clarity / readability

---

The function returns a `List<T>`; each element in the list represents a token that consists of one of the following:

- `char`
- `Wildcards` enum value (defined below)
- an instance of `PatternGrouping` -- an alternates grouping

Each alternates grouping contains one or more ranges, represented using a value tuple; a single character is represented as a range with the same start and end character.

---

```
using OneOf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Shared {
    public enum Wildcards {
        SingleCharacter,
        MultipleCharacter
    }

    // Single characters within a group are represented by a group with the same start and end character
    public class PatternGroup : List<(char start, char end)> {
        public PatternGroup(bool isPositive = true) => IsPositive = isPositive;
        public bool IsPositive { get; set; } = true;
    }

    public class LikePattern : List<OneOfBase<char, Wildcards, PatternGroup>> {
        public static LikePattern ParseVBLike(string pattern) {
            var ret = new LikePattern();

            int pos = -1;
            int lastPos = pattern.Length - 1;

            PatternGroup currentGroup = null;

            char ch;
            while (pos < lastPos) {
                advanceChar();

                if (currentGroup == null) {

                    if (ch == '?') {
                        ret.Add(Wildcards.SingleCharacter);
                    } else if (ch == '*') {
                        ret.Add(Wildcards.MultipleCharacter);
                    } else if (ch == '#') {
                        ret.Add(new PatternGroup() {
                            {'0','9' }
                        });
                    } else if (ch == '[') {
                        currentGroup = new PatternGroup();
                        if (nextChar() == '!') {
                            advanceChar();
                            currentGroup.IsPositive = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        ret.Add(ch);
                    }

                } else {

                    var start = ch;
                    if (ch == ']') {
                        ret.Add(currentGroup);
                        currentGroup = null;
                    } else if (nextChar() == '-' && nextChar(2) != ']') {
                        advanceChar();
                        advanceChar();
                        currentGroup.Add(start, ch);
                    } else {
                        currentGroup.Add(ch, ch);
                    }

                }
            }

            if (currentGroup != null) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Missing group end.");
            }

            return ret;

            void advanceChar(bool ignoreEnd = false) {
                pos += 1;
                if (pos <= lastPos) {
                    ch = pattern[pos];
                } else if (ignoreEnd) {
                    ch = '\x0';
                } else {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected end of text");
                }
            }

            char nextChar(int offset = 1) => pos + offset > lastPos ? '\x0' : pattern[pos + offset];
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Usage looks like this (source of [functions](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreesInVBandCS/blob/master/Shared/LikePatternClasses.cs#L88), [usage](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreesInVBandCS/blob/master/CSharp_LikeVisitor/LikeVisitor.cs#L32)):

```
private static string MapSqlSpecialCharacters(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case '%':
        case '_':
        case '[':
            return "[" + ch + "]";
        default:
            return ch.ToString();
    }
}

public static string GetSQLLike(LikePattern pattern) => pattern.Joined("", x => x.Match(
    ch => MapSqlSpecialCharacters(ch),
    wildcard => (wildcard == Wildcards.SingleCharacter ? '_' : '%').ToString(),
    patternGroup => {
        string ret = "";
        if (patternGroup.IsPositive) { ret += '^'; }
        return ret + String.Join("",
            patternGroup.Select(range =>
                range.start == range.end ? 
                    $"{range.start}" :
                    $"{range.start}-{range.end}"
        );
    }
));

var tokenized = ParseVBLike(oldPattern);
var newPattern = GetSQLLike(tokenized);
```

The following XUnit test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void Test1() {
    var pattern = "a[L-P]#[!c-e]";
    var result = ParseVBLike(pattern);
    Assert.Collection(
        result,
        item => Assert.Equal('a', item),
        item => {
            PatternGroup grp = item.AsT2;
            Assert.True(grp.IsPositive);
            Assert.Equal(
                new List<(char,char)> { ('L', 'P') },
                grp.ToList()
            );
        },
        item => {
            PatternGroup grp = item.AsT2;
            Assert.True(grp.IsPositive);
            Assert.Equal(
                new List<(char, char)> { ('0', '9') },
                grp.ToList()
            );
        },
        item => {
            PatternGroup grp = item.AsT2;
            Assert.False(grp.IsPositive);
            Assert.Equal(
                new List<(char, char)> { ('c', 'e') },
                grp.ToList()
            );
        }
    );
}
```

as does this one:

```
[Fact]
public void TestWithAsterisk() {
    var pattern = "a*b";
    var result = ParseVBLike(pattern);
    Assert.Collection(
        result,
        item => Assert.Equal('a', item),
        item => Assert.Equal(Wildcards.MultipleCharacter, item),
        item => Assert.Equal('b', item)
    );
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97956/discussion-on-question-by-zev-spitz-function-to-parse-vb-net-like-pattern).

Answer (score 3):

IMO the use of `OneOfBase` as a kind of imitation of discriminated unions makes a lot of noise in your code and makes it more difficult to read than it has to be.

Instead I would define a more traditional class structure, where each class holds information about each pattern or token type:

```
  abstract class LikeToken
  {
    public abstract bool Match(string value, ref int start);
    public abstract string ToSQL();
    public abstract string ToVB();

    internal LikeToken Next { get; set; }
  }

  // Any constant char eg: 'a'
  class SingleChar : LikeToken
  {
    public SingleChar(char value)
    {
      Value = value;
    }

    public char Value { get; }

    public override bool Match(string value, ref int start)
    {
      if (start < value.Length && value[start] == Value)
      {
        start++;
        return Next.Match(value, ref start);
      }

      return false;
    }
  }

  // ?
  class AnySingleChar : LikeToken
  {
    // TODO implement the behavior
  }

  // *
  class ZeroOrMoreChars : LikeToken
  {
    // TODO implement the behavior
  }

  // 0 - 9
  class DigitChar : LikeToken
  {
    // TODO implement the behavior
  }

  // [a-z0-9] or [^a-z0-9]
  class CharList : LikeToken
  {
    public CharList(string charList)
    {
    }

    public bool IsPositive { get; private set; }

    // TODO implement the behavior
  }
```

As shown above the `Match()` method can be used to match each char in the string to test, and it will be independent of if the pattern originally was a VB or SQL pattern.
The methods `ToSQL()` and `ToVB()` should be used to reconstruct the pattern and hence act as a conversion mechanism between the two languages.

The `Next` member can be used to chain the tokens in a linked list which can be useful in the match process, because some of the patterns have to look ahead to find the optimal match - but you have surely already a design for that.

---

Parsing the pattern could then for VB be something like:

```
  public class LikePattern
  {
    internal LikePattern(IReadOnlyList<LikeToken> tokens)
    {
       // TODO Initialize the tokens Next member to form a linked list and the head member with the first token
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
    private readonly LikeToken head

    public bool Match(string value)
    {
      // TOD Implement
    }

    public static LikePattern Parse(string pattern)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
        throw new ArgumentException("Can not be an empty string", nameof(pattern));

      List<LikeToken> tokens = new List<LikeToken>();
      int index = 0;

      while (index < pattern.Length)
      {
        char current = pattern[index];

        switch (current)
        {
          case '?':
            tokens.Add(new AnySingleChar());
            break;
          case '*':
            tokens.Add(new ZeroOrMoreChars());
            break;
          case '#':
            tokens.Add(new DigitChar());
            break;
          case '[':
            int start = index;
            while (index < pattern.Length && pattern[index] != ']')
            {
              index++;
            }
            if (index >= pattern.Length)
              throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing a closing square bracket for last char list");
            tokens.Add(new CharList(pattern.Substring(start, index - start + 1)));
            break;
          default:
            tokens.Add(new SingleChar(pattern[index]));
            break;
        }

        index++;
      }

      return new LikePattern(tokens);
    }
  }
```

And a similar method could easily be made for SQL.

---

Some convenient extension methods could be:

```
  public static class LikeExtensions
  {
    public static bool Like(this string value, string pattern, out string message)
    {
      LikePattern likePattern = LikePattern.Parse(pattern);
      bool result = likePattern.Match(value);
      if (!result)
        message = likePattern.Message;
      else
        message = "";
      return result;
    }

    public static bool Like(this string value, LikePattern pattern)
    {
      return pattern.Match(value);
    }
  }
```

---

And usage:

```
  LikePattern likePattern = LikePattern.Parse("[!e-z]bcd");

  string value = "abcd";
  bool result = value.Like(likePattern);
```